# How does the quantum wave function behave within a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, wavefunction, event-horizon, qft-in-curved-spacetime

We have recently studied the wave function in physics and I was wondering how this behaves within a black hole, since within a black hole position cannot be determined so surely the wave function breaks down

Comment: Short answer: no one knows. But note that the wave function is a concept from quantum mechanics, which is non-relativistic. And black holes are one of the "most relativistic things", loosely speaking.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer ah I see thank you for the answer, is there any further reading you know of I could read to learn more about the wave function because my course only lightly touches on it but it seems incredibly interesting but anything I try to read online is either extremely complex or too simple!

Comment: How much calculus and linear algebra do you know? Do you want to learn the ins and outs of the wave function (i.e. to learn some fundamental quantum mechanics)? Or do you prefer a popular science treatment?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer my knowledge of calculus and linear algebra is reasonably strong I am a first year maths student at Oxford and we heard of the wave function whilst learning more in-depth probability. Ideally I would want to learn the ins and outs as I hope to after my maths degree go into a masters in quantum mechanics

Comment: In that case I recommend Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics book. There are many physics books I think are good, but this one I straight up *enjoy* reading. Others will have different preferences of course. Sakurai is another popular one, slightly more mathematical.

Comment: Perfect thanks for all your help I’ll give those both a read!

Comment: “*within a black hole position cannot be determined*” - Why?

Comment: @safesphere since if you were to imagine yourself falling into a black hole to an outside observer your position can only be determined until you reach the event horizon and once you have reached the event horizon, as perceived by the external viewer, your position in neither space or time can be accurately determined

Comment: @safesphere the only position we could assume someone to have would be at the singularity however since our knowledge of a singularity (see information paradox) is so little this cannot be assumed

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this question admits a meaningful answer.

Whose coordinate system are we writing the wave function in?

If we're in free fall next to the particle, we never measure an event horizon.

If we're in a frame that measures a gravitational event horizon between us and the particle, we never measure the particle to have crossed the event horizon.

Even if we imagine a "there and now" for the particle to exist in and infer its "real current location", the wave function expresses the answer to the question, "If we take a measurement, what is the probability that we find the particle in such and such a state?" It's on the far side of an event horizon, *we cannot measure it*, therefore the wave function of the particle inside the event horizon is indistinguishable from that of a particle that does not exist.

Comment: I’m don’t know much about quantum mechanics it was really just a thought that popped into my head, so is the wave function relative to the reference frame of the measurer?

Comment: @Willthorne I think that might make a good question on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer yet to your question. This is the problem of unification of   gravity and quantum mechanics. See, e.g., string theory.

P.S.: no one knows what happens at the singularity. See, information paradox. Even unitarity (|psi|^2 = 1) falls in question!